# REST endpoint as Kafka Sink

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka world. We are planning to set up Kafka to fulfill our data streaming needs. The sink in our case, is REST endpoint. What connectors are available to support Kafka => REST endpoint connectivity? This is similar to how AWS simple queues or topics work.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no certified HTTP sink for Apache Kafka. Why not simply create a kafka consumer and for every message (or message batch) make a REST call to your service?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing out of the box that I'm aware of but akka-streams feels well suited for this use-case.

The source would be a Kafka message stream created using akka-stream-kafka (aka reactive-kafka) and the sink the akka-http client (flow-based variant):
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.6/scala/http/client-side/request-level.html#flow-based-variant

Integration patterns for akka-streams are (starting to be) documented under the name alpakka:
http://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/